# SMOTE-NC not working, Error: Pandas output does not support sparse data

Tags: machine-learning, python, logistic-regression, class-imbalance, smotenc

I want to get my SMOTENC to work, but i've been failing successfully

```
# set_config(transform_output="pandas") # Keeps the names in the pipeline  
 
target = 'target' 
X = df.drop(target, axis=1)
count_col = [col for col in X.columns if col.startswith('Count') or 'count' in col] # [col for col in X.columns if col.lower().startswith('count')]
cols_to_drop = ['Col1', 'Col2','Col3'] 

X = X.drop(columns=cols_to_drop)
# X = X.drop(columns=count_col)
threshold_value = 'Y'  # Replace with the actual threshold value

# Convert target variable to binary classification
y = (df[target] == threshold_value).astype(int)

# Make X and y Dataframes
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
y = pd.DataFrame(y)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

feature_selector = GenericUnivariateSelect(score_func = f_classif, mode = 'k_best', param = 22)

# Identify categorical and numerical columns

categorical_features = X.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns 
numerical_features = X.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns
categorical_indices = [X_train.columns.get_loc(col) for col in categorical_features]  

print(f'Shape of Training Data:{X_train.shape}')
print(f'Shape of Testing Data:{X_test.shape}')

smotenc = SMOTENC(categorical_features=categorical_indices, sampling_strategy='auto', random_state=42)

X_train_resampled, y_train_resampled = smotenc.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```

I do not know what else to do, i'm stuck i've tried fixing this over and over again, I've tried converting the data to arrays, to a numpy array. What exactly am i doing wrong?

But i keep getting an error that:

```
ValueError: Pandas output does not support sparse data.
```

Comment: I think the problem may be your first line - set_config(transform_output="pandas"), can you run without this?